# Add to map only certain types of MODIS Land-Cover In Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, land-cover

I'm trying to create a map on Google Earth Engine with only some Land-Cover class, but I can't find a solution to this problem.

I'm using this MODIS dataset: MODIS/061/MCD12Q1/2002_01_01
I'm using this type of Land-Cover: LC_Type1

From LC_Type1, I just want to use the classes from 1 to 5 (the ones described as Evergreen Needleleaf Forests, Evergreen Broadleaf Forests, Needleleaf Forests, Broadleaf Forest, and Mixed Forests)

How do I filter only these 5 classes?

The final aim is to use these classes to extract NPP values from another MODIS dataset for computing a time-series chart of yearly NPP. This last part is not a problem because is something I just manage to resolve. My only problem is with the "filtering" of these land-cover classes.

I tried to filter these classes but it is always giving me errors.

I'm stuck here:

```js
// MODIS Land-Cover dataset
var landcover = ee.Image("MODIS/061/MCD12Q1/2002_01_01")
                  .select('LC_Type1')
                  .clip(roi)


// visualization palette
var LCVis = {
  min: 1.0,
  max: 17.0,
  palette: [
    '05450a', '086a10', '54a708', '78d203', '009900', 'c6b044', 'dcd159',
    'dade48', 'fbff13', 'b6ff05', '27ff87', 'c24f44', 'a5a5a5', 'ff6d4c',
    '69fff8', 'f9ffa4', '1c0dff'
  ],
};


Map.centerObject(roi, 8)
Map.addLayer(landcover, LCVis, 'MODIS land-cover')
```

I tried

```js
// MODIS Land-Cover dataset
var landcover = ee.Image("MODIS/061/MCD12Q1/2002_01_01")
                  .select('LC_Type1', [1,5])
                  .clip(roi)
```

but it's not working.

Is there a solution?

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mask the other pixels

```
// create mask with pixels values less than or equal to 5
var mymask = landcover.lte(5);

// Apply mask
var forest = landcover.updateMask(mymask);

// Visualize
Map.addLayer(forest, LCVis, 'MODIS forest')
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!